# Selenium: Trying to log in with cookies - "Can only set cookies for current domain"

Tags: python, post, selenium, cookies, http-post

**What I am trying to achieve**

I am trying to log in to a website where cookies must be enabled using Selenium headless, I am using PhantomJS for driver.

**Problem**

I first recorded the procedure using Selenium IDE where it works fine using Firefox (not headless). Then I exported the code to Python and now I can't log in because it's throwing an error saying "Can only set Cookies for the current domain". I don't know why I am getting this problem, am I not on the correct domain?

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import unittest, time, re

        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://login.example.com"

        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.base_url)

        all_cookies = self.driver.get_cookies()

        # It prints out all cookies and values just fine
        for cookie in all_cookies
            print cookie['name'] + " --> " + cookies['value']

        # Set cookies to driver
        for s_cookie in all_cookies:
            c = { s_cookie['name'] : s_cookie['value']}
            # This is where it's throwing an error saying "Can only set Cookies for current domain
            driver.add_cookie(c)

        ...
```

**What I've tried**

I've tried saving the cookies in a dict, going to another domain, going back to original domain and added the cookies and then trying to log in but it still doesn't work (as suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22507204/selenium-cookie-with-another-domain))

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you're trying to login to one page, then leave that site and go to another site, login there, and then come back to site 1, I would be very tempted to force a login with your script again. I'd also suggest starting 2 drivers, one for site A and one for site B. `driver1 = webdriver.PhandomJS()` & `driver2 = webdriver.PhantomJS()`

Answer (score 5):

Investigate the each cookies pairs. I ran into the similar issues and some of the cookies belonged to Google. You need to make sure cookies are being added only to the current Domain and also belong to the same Domain. In that case your exception is expected. On a side note, if I recall it correctly you cannot use `localhost` to add the cookies if you are doing so. Change to IP address. Also, investigate the cookies you are getting specially domain and expiry information. See, if they are returning `null`

**Edit**

I did this simple test on Gmail to show what you have done wrong. At first look I did not notice that you are trying to grab partial cookie, a pair, and add that to the domain. Since, the cookie does not have any Domain, path, expiry etc. information it was trying to add the cookie to current domain(127.0.0.1) and throwing some misleading info that did not quite make sense. Notice: in order to be a valid cookie it must have to have the correct Domain and expiry information which you have been missing.

```
import unittest
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium import webdriver


__author__ = 'Saifur'


class CookieManagerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("E:\\working\\selenium.python\\selenium\\resources\\phantomjs.exe")
        self.driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "Email").send_keys("userid")
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "next").click()
        self.driver.find_element(By.ID, "Passwd").send_keys("supersimplepassword")
        self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[type='submit'][value='Sign in']").click()
        self.driver.maximize_window()

    def test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        listcookies = driver.get_cookies()

        for s_cookie in listcookies:
            # this is what you are doing
            c = {s_cookie['name']: s_cookie['value']}
            print("*****The partial cookie info you are doing*****\n")
            print(c)
            # Should be done
            print("The Full Cookie including domain and expiry info\n")
            print(s_cookie)
            # driver.add_cookie(s_cookie)


    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

> Console output:
>
> D:\Python34\python.exe "D:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Educational Edition 1.0.1\helpers\pycharm\utrunner.py" E:\working\selenium.python\selenium\python\FirstTest.py::CookieManagerTest true
>   Testing started at 9:59 AM ...
>
> *******The partial cookie info you are doing*******
>
> {'PREF': 'ID=*******:FF=0:LD=en:TM=*******:LM=*******:GM=1:S=*******'}
>
> **The Full Cookie including domain and expiry info**
>
> {'httponly': False, 'name': '*******', 'value': 'ID=*******:FF=0:LD=en:TM=*******:LM=1432393656:GM=1:S=iNakWMI5h_2cqIYi', 'path': '/', 'expires': 'Mon, 22 May 2017 15:07:36 GMT', 'secure': False, 'expiry': *******, 'domain': '.google.com'}
>
> **Notice: I just replaced some info with `*******` on purpose**

Comment: I think you are correct that I am adding the cookies from `localhost`, but how do I make the driver add them from the domain? The cookies contain information about the domain, which are `.example.com` and `example.com`.

Comment: You should be using get cookies and add cookies on same domain. Is that what you asking?

Comment: Looking at my code - is that not what I am doing? I'm not going to another domain before adding the cookies, and this is why I am confused.

Comment: Yes, but what happen is when you grab the list of cookies(depending on your application) there are certain technologies used by the application which belong to different domain. In my case it was Google. All, you need to do just print the domain for every cookie and see if they belong to your domain or add conditions to filter them out

Comment: I've pinponted the issue: the Selenium request header contains `Host : 127.0.0.1` which I cannot seem to change (Selenium wont let me). Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Thanks for the added info! I'm still getting the same result though. Why is it even necessary to add the cookies, they are all visible in `driver.get_cookies()` so why do I have to add them again?

Comment: I am confused now. Why are you doing `driver.add_cookie(c)` then?  I thought your intention is to grab the cookies for certain user and reuse them later  for another purpose. Isn't it? And, provide some specific information what the error is. At least, selenium, python, phantomJs versions etc. I have verified with latest selenium, python and phantomJs version for http and https protocols and all work as expected

Comment: And, you need to grab the cookies after **logging in** that's very necessary. Because there are authentication, authorization related to the cookies. If you are planning to use the cookies for login then make sure you log in and then grab the list of cookies and then add them to the domain back

Comment: I need the cookies to be able to log in, otherwise I'm re-directed to a page where it says I can't log in, and I know it's because of the cookies (if I turn of cookies in my browser I get same result). I'm using v2.4.5 for selenium, python 2.7.3 and phantomjs 2.0.1-dev on a raspberry pi 2 B.

Comment: I tried switching to Firefox driver (in case website doesn't allow PhantomJS in useragent), but still being re-directed to page telling me I can't log in.

Comment: That's a different issue and probably related to `iframe` and how does that work manually?

Comment: Using Selenium IDE for Firefox works just fine. Now I seem to be getting other problems. I've changed tactis - now I'm using requests library for Python but I'm getting a "TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects.". Sigh.. Oh well, I guess I'll close this thread. Have any ideas on that?

Comment: Can you provide any reproducible scenario? I a not sure why it's happening

Answer (score 2):

I was going to just add a comment onto the bottom of what @Saifur said above, but I figured I had enough new content to warrant a full comment.

The revelation for me, having this exact same error, was that using Selenium works exactly the same as if you're actually opening up your browser and physically clicking and typing things. With this in mind, if you enter the user/pass into Selenium and press `click()`, your Selenium driver will, upon successful authentican, automatically have the cookie in it. Thus negating any need to smash in my saved (probably going to expire soon) cookie. I felt a little silly realizing this. Made everything so much simpler.

Using @Saifur's code above as an template, I've made some adjustments and removed what I feel is a bit excessive of an extra whole class for the execution in this example.

```
url = 'http://domainname.com'
url2 = 'http://domainname.com/page'
USER = 'superAwesomeRobot'
PASS = 'superSecretRobot'

# initiates your browser 
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS() 
# browses to your desired URL
driver.get(url)             
# searches for the user or email field on the page, and inputs USER   
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys(USER)
# searches for the password field on the page, and inputs PASS
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys(PASS)
# finds the login button and click you're in
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click()
```

from here you can browse to the page you want to address

```
driver.get(url2)
```

**note:** if you have a modern site that auto loads when you scroll down, it might be handy to use this:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I would also like to note, @simeg, that Selenium automatically is supposed to wait until the page has returned that it's loaded (and yes, I've had the AJAX issue that is being referred to, so sometimes it is necessary to wait a few seconds - what page takes more then 30 seconds to load?!). The way that you're running your wait command is just waiting for PhantomJS to load, not the actual page itself so it seems of no use to me considering the built in function:

> The driver.get method will navigate to a page given by the URL. WebDriver will wait until the page has fully loaded (that is, the “onload” event has fired) before returning control to your test or script. It’s worth noting that if your page uses a lot of AJAX on load then WebDriver may not know when it has completely loaded.
>
> source: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#example-explained

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

Some webpages use too many keys in the cookies not supported by webdriver, then you get an "errorMessage":"Can only set Cookies for the current domain", even though you are 100% sure that you are setting cookies for the current domain. An example of such webpage is "https://stackoverflow.com/". In this case, you need to make sure that only the required keys are added to the cookies, as mentioned in some previous posts.

```
driver.add_cookie({k: cookie[k] for k in   ('name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'expiry') if k in cookie})
```

In constrast, some webpages use too few keys in the cookies, that are required by webdriver, then you get an "errorMessage":"Can only set Cookies for the current domain", after you fix the first problem. An example of such webpage is "https://github.com/". You need to add key 'expiry' to the cookies for this webpage.

```
    for k in ('name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'expiry'):
        if k not in list(cookie.keys()):
            if k == 'expiry':
                cookie[k] = 1475825481
```

Putting them all together, the complete code is as below:

```
# uncommented one of the following three URLs to test
#targetURL = "http://pythonscraping.com"
targetURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
#targetURL = "https://github.com/"

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get(targetURL)
driver.implicitly_wait(1)
#print(driver.get_cookies())

savedCookies = driver.get_cookies()
driver2 = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver2.get(targetURL)
driver2.implicitly_wait(1)
driver2.delete_all_cookies()

for cookie in savedCookies:
    # fix the 2nd problem
    for k in ('name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'expiry'):
        if k not in list(cookie.keys()):
            if k == 'expiry':
                cookie[k] = 1475825481
    # fix the 1st problem
    driver2.add_cookie({k: cookie[k] for k in ('name', 'value', 'domain', 'path', 'expiry') if k in cookie})    
print(cookie)   

driver2.get(targetURL)
driver2.implicitly_wait(1)
```