# How Python3 urllib use selenium cookie

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, urllib, cookiejar

I use selenium simulation log in a website,and I want to use urllib with the cookie that it is get from selenium driver.But there is crash with this log.

```
AttributeError: 'SimpleCookie' object has no attribute 'domain'
```

My code is these please help me how to fix it.

```
cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
cookie_support = urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(
    cookie_support)
all_cookies = driver.get_cookies()
cookies = {}
for s_cookie in all_cookies:
    cookies[s_cookie["name"]] = s_cookie["value"]
cookie = http.cookies.SimpleCookie()
cookie.load(cookies)
cj.set_cookie(cookie)
result = opener.open(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it right.

> *You need to have correct Domain and expiry info to set a cookie with `Selenium`*
>   Why do not you simply grab the list of cookies and use that. There are some other factors involved when it comes to `Selenium`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292025/selenium-trying-to-log-in-with-cookies-can-only-set-cookies-for-current-doma/30293686#30293686)

```
def test(self):
        driver = self.driver
        listcookies = driver.get_cookies()

        for s_cookie in listcookies:
            driver.add_cookie(s_cookie)
```

Comment: Beacuse I want to reply the posts in mulit threading,and when I open too many thread,it will open too many browsers and take too much memery.So I want use urllib to reply the post and use the cookie in Selenium.