# My pickled cookies won't work in selenium - python?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to open up a selenium instance then login in to any site manually and then save the session. when the browser opens and goes to the login page I login and then I go to the taskbar in firefox and then preferences then security then tick remember login for sites.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pickle

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
continu = raw_input("Press Enter when you've logged in")
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/twitter/twitter_loggins.pkl", "wb"))
```

when I open the browser in another python file and set the webdriver with the cookie it doesn't remember the login info. I'm trying to make it so it logins automatically.

EDIT:
This is my other file that I run to load the cookie

```
def load_cookie(file1):
    with open(file1, 'rb') as cookie:
        return pickle.load(cookie)

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
cookie = load_cookie("/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/twitter/twitter_loggins.pkl")
driver.add_cookie(cookie)
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without setting the cookies the browser does not recognize you and let you log in automatically. But to set cookies you need to be on same domain. Then set the cookies and refresh the page

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://twitter.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("/home/ro/A_Python_Scripts/twitter/twitter_loggins.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    #del cookie['domain'] # uncomment this if you get different domain error
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.get("https://twitter.com") # Reload & you will be logged in automatically
```

Comment: Thanks but that's what I'm doing I load the pickled cookies in another py file, but it won't remember the login info, I've edited my question to include the code I'm using.

Comment: you cannot add cookies on different domain. add driver.get("https://twitter.com") before calling load_cookie. it is working for me

Comment: @Eric driver.add_cookie() expects a dictionary but you are passing a list of dictionaries to it. so try adding them one by one in loop. that might be the reason

Comment: Thanks, I think it was that I was passing in a list and I was adding cookies from another domain. I tried the code you showed me and I got an exception that said I can only add from the same domain, in the traceback it said I was trying to add cookies from google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292025/selenium-trying-to-log-in-with-cookies-can-only-set-cookies-for-current-doma I'm going to have a read up about it and filter the cookies. I also tried a try, except, pass in the code block that didn't work either it just ran without any errors and it didn't log in. Thankyou for your help.

Comment: @Eric hmm sometimes when i get that error i just remove the domain name  from the cookie. I don't know whether it is the right way but it works for me. updated my code

Comment: Thanks that's working for me now, I tried re-directing to googles domain to add each one of their cookies but it didn't return any errors but it didn't sign me in either, strange.