# Add cookie with domain

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, phantomjs

I am trying to load a web page that requires authentication with selenium/ phantom driver. I have the required cookie from my session which I pass over to the the `driver.add_cookie` but I always get the error saying

> Can only set Cookies for the current domain.

Edit: After calling `add_cookie` with the domain name, I still get the error

> Unable to set cookie

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap, service_args=service_args)
driver.get(url)
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'session', 'value': session, 'domain': 'localhost:25000', 'path': '/'})
```

I tried setting the proxy as follows:

```
service_args = ['--proxy=127.0.0.1:25000', '--proxy-type=http']
```

but it still makes the request from a different port

I also want to set the user agent but this is  not working too:

```
dcap = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
```

Anyhow, everything works fine when I use curl with the terminal

The error message headers also suggests that the request is a POST request and from the logs I can also see that it gets redirected to the login page

How can I set the cookies for the current domain?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30292025/selenium-trying-to-log-in-with-cookies-can-only-set-cookies-for-current-doma ...it says to try using IP instead of localhost.